# JavaScript Polling Issue

Tags: javascript

When I click "End", it doesn't destroy (lack of a better word) the `setTimeout` function.
You'll notice the json file is called, at some point 6 times

**Note:** I left a console.log in the code to show you the issue I speak of (so ensure you have your console open).

**Requirements:** By default the json file should load once, then upon clicking "Start", the json file needs to be called (every x secs) until "End" is clicked (in which case the polling will stop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `completePoll()` on click of "end" link.

FYI: The `_this.completePoll(cfg);` with in the `setTimeout` clears the previous timeout handler which has already executed.

---

Also, if you called the `startPoll` function more than once, without clearing the current timeout, you will end up creating another timeout cycle and will overwrite the previous handler.

```
if(_this.setPolling){clearTimeout(_this.setPolling);_this.setPolling=0;}
```

Add the above line in the beginning of the `startPoll` function which will kill the running timer.

Comment: I think your solution may have fixed this. Does the code look correct now (as you advised)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in your page, it looks like you need to call `window.poller.completePoll(cfg)` when you want the timer to stop.  That will clear the next pending timeout and cause it to stop polling.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In theory that should work; however, if you click "End" & "Start" a few times, you'll see the issue I speak of. You'll see the number of requests triple after clicking End/Start :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about.  Your code doesn't call completePoll() when the end link is clicked.  That allows multiple timers to stack up.  The way this code works, you must call completePoll before you start a new one.  You also have to protect against start being clicked multiple times.

Comment: I left out the aforementioned code (provided by Mr. Jose). It works a charm now. Is there any additional syntax that you suggest? Thank you for your response.